# rule to extract key+phrases from a text document

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit-qi

I want to extract the key phrases from the document: "something KEY phrase END something ... ect". My rule works well but the result does not contain of key name. What should be the rule in order to get a string: "KEY phrase". Thank you for the advice.

```
std::vector<std::string> doc; 
bool r = qi::phrase_parse(first,last, 
  ( qi::omit[*(qi::char_-"KEY")] 
    >> qi::lexeme[ "KEY"
    >> *(qi::char_-"KEY" -"END")] ) % "END"
, qi::space, doc);
```

Comment: What is the type of `doc`?

Comment: (Also, you forgot to tell us the type of `doc`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qi::lit(...)` doesn't synthesize an attribute.

`qi::string(...)` does.

Replace `"KEY"` with qi::string("KEY"), likely. (hard to tell without knowing the type of `doc`)

```
bool r = qi::phrase_parse(first,last, 
  ( qi::omit[*(qi::char_-"KEY")] 
    >> qi::lexeme[ qi::string("KEY")
    >> *(qi::char_-"KEY" -"END")] ) % "END"
, qi::space, doc);
```

**BONUS** See also **[`seek[]` parser directive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/spirit/repository/doc/html/spirit_repository/qi_components/directives/seek.html)** from the Spirit Repository:

> The `seek[]` parser-directive skips all input until the subject parser matches.

Here's what I'd do:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ffbc0522bd27925)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi_seek.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace qr = boost::spirit::repository::qi;

extern std::string const sample; // below

int main() {
    auto f(sample.begin()), l(sample.end());

    std::vector<std::string> phrases;

    if (qi::parse(f,l, *qi::as_string[
                qr::seek[qi::string("KEY")] >> *(qi::char_ - "END")
            ], phrases)) 
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < phrases.size(); ++i) 
            std::cout << "keyphrase #" << i << ": '" << phrases[i] << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
keyphrase #0: 'KEY@v/0qwJTjgFQwNmose7LiEmAmKpIdK3TPmkCs@'
keyphrase #1: 'KEY@G1TErN1QSSKi17BSnwBKML@'
keyphrase #2: 'KEY@pWhBKmc0sD+o@'
keyphrase #3: 'KEY@pwgjNJ0FvWGRezwi74QdIQdmUuKVyquWuvXz4tBOXqMMqco@'
keyphrase #4: 'KEY@aJ3QUfLh3AqfKyxcUSiDbanZmCNGza6jb6pZ@'
keyphrase #5: 'KEY@bYJzitZUyXlgPA009qBpleHIJ9uJUSdJO78iisUgHkoqUpf+oXZQF9X/7v2fikgemCD@'
```

Sample data included in a comment in this answer: /here/

Comment: @stansy I've included a sample, based on `repository::qi::seek`

Comment: Brilliant solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to SO :) See also [how does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Final benchmark:

- Spirit Qi (sahe's solution above) -
  Items count:  5585  Elapsed time:  183.676 seconds
- Boost regex -
  Items count:  5585  Elapsed time:  197.684 seconds
- Xpressive regex -
  Items count:  5585  Elapsed time:  232.597 seconds

Data size: 23.9 MB text file